# Change div order when going from mobile to desktop

Tags: html, css, media-queries

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-7>
        <div>
            div A
        </div>
        <div>
            div B
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-5>
        <div>
            div C
        </div>
        <div>
            div D
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    div E
</div>
```

Apparently, the result is like:

```
div A        div C
div B        div D
div E
```

Now, what I want is to have the following result in **mobile**:

```
div A
div C
div B
div D
div E
```

How may I achieve that by using **media queries**? Is that possible? I have implemented the `desktop-first approach`, but in case it is easier to start from a `mobile-first approach` and implement then the above desktop structure, it is fine.

Comment: first the html struture is not valid as there is no row/container assuming you are using V3 of bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the order of columns in smaller screens but you can do that in large screens.

So change the order of your columns.

So in mobile main content is displayed first.

By using `col-lg-push` and `col-lg-pull` we can reorder the columns in large screens

[Example](https://www.codeply.com/go/wgzJXs3gel)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap, the existing classes like `col-sm-12` or `col-md-2` and so should do it automatically with the default screen parameter of bootstrap, i think it becomes more difficult using div and media queries